# Ext JS 6.2.0: defaultValue of boolan filter gridcolumn set to null doesen't work

Tags: extjs

I'm new with Ext JS. I have the next problem:

I want to set a boolean filter to a gridcolumn on Ext JS 6.2.0. I was guided by the official documentation but what I did does not work.

I set the defaultValue of boolean filter to null beacause I don't want either option to be checked by default, but doesn't work, It's taking as default value false.

What setting am I missing?

This is my code:

```js
columns: {
    defaults: {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        align: 'left'
    },
    items: [
        {
            dataIndex: 'PorCalibVerif',
            name: 'PorCalibVerif',
            align: 'center',
            flex: 1,
            text: 'Calib/Verif',
            id: 'calibracion-elementoMedicion-CalibVerif',
            filter: {
                dataIndex: 'IsCalibVerif',
                type: 'boolean',                            
                defaultValue: null,                            
                yesText: 'Calibration',
                noText: 'Verification'
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in ExtJS 6.2 that was fixed already in version 6.5. If you look at [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/guides/whats_new/release_notes.html) and search for `EXTJS-23152` you will see this bug that was fixed in 6.5.

Check out [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3oni). It works as it should with version `Ext JS 6.5.0.775 Triton`.

Now change the version in the upper right part to `Ext JS 6.2.1.167 Triton` and run the fiddle again. Now the default filter option is (wrongly) set to `No`.

So you should upgrade your framework version to get it work.

Comment: You are welcome. If it solves your problem please consider marking my answer as accepted.